# How to center view on both 3.5 and 5 inch devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a view with few controls, and I want it to be centered vertically regardless of device.

I tried auto layout without much help.

I tried Size Inspector - Arrange - Center Horizontally in container, but it works only in one type of screen. So if I arrange in 4 inch display it will too low on 3.5 inch, and if I arrange on 3.5 inch it will be too high on 4 inch.

What can be done about that?

Comment: @Downvoter please detail reason for downvote so user can improve question if possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up by using two different XIBs, one for 3.5 inch and one for 4 inch devices.

Comment: @Downvoter please detail reason for downvote so user can improve answer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the center of the of the main view that you are placing onto by doing

```
 CGPoint viewCenterPoint = [[self view] center];
```

this will get both the `x` and `y` positions for the center of the main view. You can set the `x` or `y` position for each one yourself like

```
CGPoint viewCenterPoint = CGPointMake([[self view] center].x, [[self view] center].y);
```

so if you wanted to have the center for `x` of main view than you can do it this way.

Once you have set the `viewCenterPoint` you can then on your new view that you want to be placed in the center of the main view you can just do.

```
 // ... all code to set myNewView up
 [myNewView setCenter:viewCenterPoint];
```

simple as, this should work across 3.5 inch and 4 inch devices as well as iPads.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the X and Y of its frame in code using `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` to get the size of the screen.

Anyways I'm pretty sure this can be done with auto layouts

Comment: oh ok! try this code:

`CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

CGFloat yValue = screenSize.height/2 - self.self.yourView.frame.size.height/2;

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(self.yourView.frame.origin.x, yValue, self.yourView.frame.size.width, self.yourView.frame.size.height);

self.yourView.frame = newRect;`